# Is it possible to use a table in Windows Forms as a matrix?

Tags: c#, winforms, matrix

I am trying to create a simple 6X8 cell matrix in which the user can click in a cell and turn it it on or off, black or white. I have been experimenting with the windows form controls and looked at the Data grid control, but so far I cannot see a way to use anything in the Winforms tool box to create a matrix.

I created the table, but cannot see a way of styling each cell individually, or use onclick events for each cell. Is this possible, if not is there another way to do this?

Comment: If you're interested, I can provide a clean, beautiful, animated, WPF-based solution to your problem. You could then integrate that in an existing winforms app by using the `ElementHost`.

Comment: I'd create my own usercontrol to do this, or worse case just use a picturebox. You'll be fighting something as heavy as table for ages, you'll probaly lose as well...

Comment: @HighCore If you want to provide a solution, then provide a solution and post it as the answer.  There's no real need to post a comment saying that you can write a solution; that's not something anyone else needs to know.

Comment: Thanks guys! My first thought was to use a picture pox and split it up into sections using coordinates, would this be possible, I would like that.

Comment: What would your solution entail HighCore it sounds like I want it :)

Comment: @Servy I did that in the past and flamed and crucified me for giving a WPF solution to a winforms problem (even when the OP accepted my solution and dropped winforms in favor of WPF to never look back)... so that's why Im asking before actually doing it.

Comment: @HighCore You would need to explain how your WPF solution would be able to be used by a winform project, if you choose to use it, and I'm not saying that nobody would ever criticize you for providing a WPF solution to a winform problem, but the fact remains stating you can provide an answer isn't helpful.  Now if you wanted to ask a question, such as, "Would it be acceptable to provide a WPF solution that you could integrate into your winform project?"  Then that's no longer a useless comment, it's a clarifying question which helps you help the OP, and is an appropriate comment.

Comment: I am definitely interested in what your solution entails HighCore I want to learn as much as I can about everything! Thank you!

Comment: @deucalion0 I posted my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution with labels being created at runtime. You need a panel to host your "matrix" and a button, all with default names. The button will paint a checkerboard on click, and you can flip the color by clicking on each cell.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  public Form1()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  const int RowCount = 6;
  const int ColumnCount = 8;
  private void button1_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < RowCount; i++)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < ColumnCount; j++)
      {
        Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.Size = new Size(20, 20);
        lbl.Location = new Point(i * 20, j * 20);
        lbl.BackColor = (i + j) % 2 == 0 ? Color.Black : Color.White;
        lbl.Click += lbl_Click;
        panel1.Controls.Add(lbl);
      }
    }

    MessageBox.Show(CountCellsOfColor(Color.Black).ToString());
  }

  private int CountCellsOfColor(Color color)
  {
    int count = 0;
    foreach (Label lbl in panel1.Controls.OfType<Label>())
    {                
      if (lbl.BackColor == color) count += 1;
    }
    return count;
  }

  private void lbl_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
  {
    Label lbl = (Label)sender;
    Color color = lbl.BackColor;
    if (color == System.Drawing.Color.Black)
    {
      color = System.Drawing.Color.White;
    }
    else
    {
      color = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
    }
    lbl.BackColor = color;
  }   
}
```

VB.NET version (original version, later converted to C#, but decided to keep in case anybody needs it):

```
Option Strict On
Public Class Form1
  Const RowCount As Integer = 6
  Const ColumnCount As Integer = 8

  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For i = 0 To RowCount - 1
      For j = 0 To ColumnCount - 1
        Dim lbl As New Label
        lbl.Size = New Size(20, 20)
        lbl.Location = New Point(i * 20, j * 20)
        lbl.BackColor = If((i + j) Mod 2 = 0, Color.Black, Color.White)
        AddHandler lbl.Click, AddressOf lbl_Click
        Panel1.Controls.Add(lbl)
      Next
    Next

    MessageBox.Show(CountCellsOfColor(Color.Black))
  End Sub

  Private Function CountCellsOfColor(color As Color) As Integer
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    For Each lbl In Panel1.Controls.OfType(Of Label)()
      If lbl.BackColor = color Then count += 1
    Next
    Return count
  End Function

  Private Sub lbl_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim lbl As Label = CType(sender, Label)
    Dim color As Color = lbl.BackColor
    If color = Drawing.Color.Black Then
      color = Drawing.Color.White
    Else
      color = Drawing.Color.Black
    End If
    lbl.BackColor = color
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: This looks great and along the lines of what I was hoping to do, if you could convert it that would be awesome, as I have never used VB. Thank you!!!

Comment: Awesome Neolisk, I will try this now, it looks great though! Cheers!

Comment: Pardon me for not being clever but do I need to still add all of these things to the form from the tool box, or will they be added automatically? I copied your code, added a panel to my form and ran it but nothing shows. Thanks!!

Comment: @deucalion0: Everything is created at runtime, triggered by the button click. Did you click the button? If you don't like this behavior, you can put that code into `Sub New`, after `InitializeComponent`; or `Form_Load`, or as required.

Comment: I figured it was the button, thanks a lot! It is loading on screen, I am messing with it now this is perfect! :)

Comment: I chose this as my answer because it was so easy to implement and it does exactly what I want. Thank you so much!

Comment: Neolisk, do you know how I could iterate through all labels to check and count how many are black or white? Thank you!

Comment: @deucalion0: Sure, just iterate through all labels and count those with the backcolor you need. See my edit for how you could do it.

Comment: One more question I promise! :) I would like to access each label individually, if label 1 is black and label 6 is white etc, how can I do this, I tried assigning them all names when they are created but it did not work. Many thanks again for all your help with this!

Comment: @deucalion0: You could create a 2D array as a class level variable, and store labels in there. Then accessing your labels by row/column index [i,j] should be pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could use DataGridView control in WinForms. You can set the needed columns and rows count. For example, for column

```
m_Grid.ColumnCount = 5;
```

and for rows

```
m_Grid.Rows.Add();
```

You could handle the CellClick, CellDoumleClick or other events and use  parameter DataGridViewCellEventArgs e ant its fields. For example,

```
m_Grid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Answer (score 0):

You better use a set of labels placed runtime:

```
List<Label> lables=new List<Label>();



var a = new Label();
labels.Add(a);
//... set positions and sizes
a.AutoSize=False;

this.Controls.Add(a);
```

with this you can later index each label in the labels array to match your row/col placement.

Comment: Thanks Felice, but I am not sure I would know how to implement this using labels, can the colours of these be set by clicking them?

Comment: A readonly texblock if you want would be the same. Just attach a proper event handler to each label. I did exactly that on a sudoku game implementation

Comment: -1 because your solution does not have the Black/White effect requested by the OP. Also, I don't see a 6 x 8 grid anywhere in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my WPF approach to this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.Window13"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window13" Height="300" Width="300">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Rows="8" Columns="6" IsItemsHost="True"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate.Resources>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="ToBlack" TargetName="RctFill" Duration="00:00:00.5">
                        <ColorAnimation From="White" To="Black" Duration="00:00:00.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="ToWhite" TargetName="RctFill" Duration="00:00:00.5">
                        <ColorAnimation From="Black" To="White" Duration="00:00:00.5"  Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </DataTemplate.Resources>
                <Button Command="{Binding ToggleCommand}">
                    <Button.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Rectangle Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" x:Name="Rct">
                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="White" x:Name="RctFill"/>
                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                            </Rectangle>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="True">
                                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ToBlack}"/>
                                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ToWhite}"/>
                                    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Button.Template>
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfApplication4
{
    public partial class Window13 : Window
    {
        public Window13()
        {
            var rnd = new Random();
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = Enumerable.Range(0, 48).Select(x => new Square() {State = rnd.Next(0,5) > 3});
        }
    }

    public class Square:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool _state;
        public bool State
        {
            get { return _state; }
            set
            {
                _state = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("State");
            }
        }

        private DelegateCommand _toggleCommand;
        public DelegateCommand ToggleCommand
        {
            get { return _toggleCommand ?? (_toggleCommand = new DelegateCommand(x => State = !State)); }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Im using the [DelegateCommand](http://wpftutorial.net/DelegateCommand.html) from WPFTutorial.Net

just copy and paste my code in a `File -> New Project -> WPF Application` and see the results for yourself. You will also need the `DelegateCommand` defintion I linked to.

The transition from black to white is animated, and you could also extend my example to animate other properties, place whatever UI you want inside each cell. Also, you will realize that this is completely resolution independent, and that resizing the Window also resizes the `UniformGrid` and therefore all the grid cells.

If you need to put this inside a winforms application you will need to use the [`ElementHost`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx)

Comment: Thanks HighCore I will look at this and try and implement it, I appreciate your help and efforts!

Comment: @FelicePollano The code behind is only 1 line setting the DataContext of the `Window`. Where is the lack of good practice?

Comment: I am still interested in your answer, I did select another question as my the answer but I will still try your solution when I have the time, thanks for this its appreciated.